# Disagreements in derivations of electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, potential-energy, dielectric

In the derivation of the potential energy of electrostatic systems we get (I am working in cgs)
$$W=\frac12\int\phi\,dq=\frac12\iiint\phi\rho\,d V \tag{1}$$ But $$\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E=4\pi\rho$$ Thus
$$\frac1{8\pi}\iiint(\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E) \phi\, dV \\ ‎\\ = \frac1{8\pi}\bigg[-\iiint\vec E\cdot(\vec\nabla\phi)\, dV+\iint\phi\vec E\cdot d\vec a\bigg] \\ ‎\\ = \frac1{8\pi}\bigg[\iiint E^2\, dV+\iint\phi\vec E\cdot d\vec a\bigg]$$
At this point everything is the same, however, after this point, Griffiths$^1$ says that one must take the volume such that the whole charge distribution is taken into account, but since $\rho=0$ for the points outside the charge distribution anyway, we can take whole space as a mathematical convenience. But here Ohanian$^2$ says that since the electric field goes to infinity, one must take the whole space as a valid step instead of just being a mathematical convenience. However here Griffiths seems more justified than Ohanian because if we look at our original equation (1) then it becomes clear that the volume that matters is that of charge distribution. Again to make it clear my issue is that according to Griffiths it is perfectly valid to use some part of space rather than the whole of it as long as charge distribution comes under it, thus we can use the above equation as it is, while Ohanian strictly says that it is wrong to do so.

So why is this disagreement between the two Authors?

Also when deriving the potentials caused by dielectrics:
$$\phi=\iiint\frac{\vec P\cdot\hat r}{r^2}\, dV'=\iiint\vec P\cdot\vec\nabla'\bigg(\frac1r\bigg)\, dV' \\ ‎\\ \phi=\iint\frac1r\vec P\cdot d\vec a'-\iiint\frac1r(\vec\nabla'\cdot\vec P)\, dV'  $$

After this Ohanian says that the surface integral must be confined to the surface of our charge distribution and we cannot take the whole space. While Schwartz$^3$ takes the whole space saying polarisation is zero there and Griffiths does not make any comment.

Again who is correct? And why are there so many disagreements?

$\\ ‎\\$
$\\ ‎\\$

$^1$David J. Griffiths, *Introduction to Electrodynamics*

$^2$Hans Ohanian, *Classical Electrodynamics*

$^3$Melvin Schwartz, *Principles of Electrodynamics*

Answer (score 1):

Griffiths is right. The "primordial" equation for calculating the internal energy of the system is the generalization of the $N$ point charges $q_i$ given by

$$
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N} q_i V(\mathrm{\mathbf{r}}_i),
$$

where $V(\mathrm{\mathbf{r}}_i)$ is the potential generated by all the other charges in the system in the position of $q_i$. The generalization yields

$$
\frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathrm{where \; charges \; are}} \rho V \mathrm{d}\tau.
$$

It is only through integration by parts that you can find it to be equal to

$$
\frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \left( \int E^2 \mathrm{d}\tau + \oint V \mathrm{\mathbf{E}} \cdot \mathrm{d\mathbf{a}} \right).
$$

What happens is: you can take the whole space in the first integral formulation and it wouldn't matter because, as you already stated, $\rho = 0$ otside the region where the charges are. When you come to this second integral formulation, the compesation of "not going to infinity" in the first integral is counterbalanced by the second. As you go further from the sources, the second integral goes to zero and the first one goes to the same value as the internal energy of the system.